# wcf: Error opening URL 'local:////star5/schema//STARTransport2005.wsdl'

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf, wsdl

I have created a wcf service consuming wsdl file. The wcf is secured with certificates which i have configured in web.config. The service have two methods one for pull and other to put. When I do a request using pull method it works but when i try to use put method i get the following error:

> Error opening URL 'local:////star5/schema//STARTransport2005.wsdl'

Here is the configuration file(web.config)

```
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <!-- Ford LDS-->
    <behavior name="Ford_WSSecBehavior">
      <clientCredentials>
        <clientCertificate storeLocation="CurrentUser" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" findValue="LD00BD.b2d.ford.com"/>
        <serviceCertificate>
          <defaultCertificate storeLocation="CurrentUser" storeName="Root" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" findValue="b2dgwqa.ford.com"/>
          <authentication revocationMode="NoCheck"/>
        </serviceCertificate>
      </clientCredentials>
      <clientVia viaUri="https://b2dgwqa.ford.com/5027/StarTransport"/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors> <binding name="Ford_starTransport" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default"/>
      </security>
    </binding> <customBinding>
    <!-- Ford LDS-->

    <binding name="Ford_Secure_https" closeTimeout="00:05:00" openTimeout="00:05:00"
      receiveTimeout="00:05:00" sendTimeout="00:05:00">
      <textMessageEncoding  messageVersion="Soap11WSAddressing10">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      </textMessageEncoding>

      <security defaultAlgorithmSuite="Basic128Rsa15" allowSerializedSigningTokenOnReply="true"
        authenticationMode="MutualCertificate" includeTimestamp="true" enableUnsecuredResponse="true"
        messageProtectionOrder="SignBeforeEncrypt" messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity10WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10" />
      <httpsTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="5000000" maxBufferSize="5000000" />
    </binding>
  </customBinding> <endpoint  address="urn:ford/star/services/v1/GenericPull"
           behaviorConfiguration="Ford_WSSecBehavior"
           binding="customBinding"
           bindingConfiguration="Ford_Secure_https"
           contract="AutoIt.Backend.FordIntegration.Proxcies.Ford.RequestSalesLeadService.starTransportPortTypes"
           name="Ford_starTransport">
    <identity>
      <dns value="b2dgwqa.ford.com" />
    </identity>
  </endpoint>

  <endpoint  address="urn:ford/star/services/v1.0/SalesLead/EU"
         behaviorConfiguration="Ford_WSSecBehavior"
         binding="customBinding"
         bindingConfiguration="Ford_Secure_https"
         contract="Proxcies.Ford.ProcessSalesLeadService.starTransportPortTypes"
         name="Ford_starTransport">
    <identity>
      <dns value="b2dgwqa.ford.com" />
    </identity>
  </endpoint>

  <endpoint  address="urn:ford/star/services/v1.0/SalesLead/EU"
       behaviorConfiguration="Ford_WSSecBehavior"
       binding="customBinding"
       bindingConfiguration="Ford_Secure_https"
       contract="AutoIt.Backend.FordIntegration.Proxcies.Ford.UpdateSalesLeadService.starTransportPortTypes"
       name="Ford_starTransport">
    <identity>
      <dns value="b2dgwqa.ford.com" />
    </identity>
  </endpoint>
```

Comment: Improved formatting.

Comment: I am amazed no body is able to answer this seems like a minor issue

Comment: I may be the only person who saw your comment there. I edited your question for formatting, but am unfamiliar with the technologies you are using. In order to get more attention from someone who could help, I suggest a) adding tags for any other technologies which may be in play here, .net perhaps, and b) including more information from any relevant log files.

Comment: Thank you so much, that was the Solution to my problem. In detail there was no version field in the header, but in the field called payloadManifest, which should be equal to the ReleaseID of the SalesLead Object, not to the VersionId, which is null...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally resolved the issue. The issue was i was missing the version number for service being called within the header of the request. When i gave the version number the error went away. This was quite a crazy error it was not pointing to the reason the error was coming. For those facing such an error, It merely occurs if you are missing something within the header of the request.